# Increment in _work directory

Tags: build, azure-devops, agent

What causes the folder name under '_work' to change on a Private Agent?

We are currently using _work/10/s etc. It has used this for the last few builds, but what would cause it to step up to using /11?

I should say we are still in the early days of using VSTS, hence why there are so few builds.

I get the feeling that it is either that we didn't initially perform any cleaning of the work directory, we do now, or that it changes when we change the build definition. Both sound plausible.

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Each build definition gets its own folder. This allows for total isolation of source code and build outputs.

You should never rely on hard-coding this path; you can reference a build's working directory with the `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` [variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#predefined-variables).

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for that. I have indeed started to use the variable, but the directory is being re-used for builds. We have now done several builds where it has used /10. So my question was more about why it's not skipping to 11, 12 etc. I think it should either use the same folder, or increment every time we do a build...one or the other! :)   There must be something that triggers that increment?

Comment: @Andrew Each build **definition** gets its own folder. So if you have two build definitions, A and B, Build Definition A will always run in, say, the `10` folder. Build Definition B will always use the `11` folder.

Answer (score 2):

There is **SourceRootMapping** folder in the working folder and there are **Mappings.json** and **SourceFolder.json** files (SourceRootMapping{guid} folder{build definition id} folder\sourceFolder.json) in this folder.

Mappings.json:

```
{
  "lastBuildFolderCreatedOn": "05/16/2018 13:20:06 +08:00",
  "lastBuildFolderNumber": 2
}
```

A SourceFolder.json:

```
{
  "build_artifactstagingdirectory": "1\\a",
  "agent_builddirectory": "1",
  "collectionUrl": "https://XXX.visualstudio.com/",
  "definitionName": "a",
  "fileFormatVersion": 3,
  "lastRunOn": "05/16/2018 13:18:06 +08:00",
  "repositoryType": "TfsGit",
  "lastMaintenanceAttemptedOn": "",
  "lastMaintenanceCompletedOn": "",
  "build_sourcesdirectory": "1\\s",
  "common_testresultsdirectory": "1\\TestResults",
  "collectionId": "21136b22-dbe8-4fae-a111-3f8c5b0fed9b",
  "definitionId": "285",
  "hashKey": "d2545895fec8eea22c60ecc24f6593a986106b80",
  "repositoryUrl": "https://starain.visualstudio.com/Scrum2017/_git/cppbase",
  "system": "build"
}
```

So, it’s easy to find that the VSTS agent increase the folder number per to **Mappings.json** and **SourceFolder.json** file is used to mapping build definition and its corresponding working folder.