# Under what circumstances VSTS automatically creates a the new repository directory for an existing repository directory?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a repo under my VSTS account for almost over a 6 months. I use a private agent to build it.
Till yesterday, it was using `C:\agent\_work\13` path while building the repo.
From today out of sudden, it created a new directory at `C:\agent\_work\201` and tried building the project. 
What could be the reason behind this?

Here's how my current directory structure looks on the private agent.

[image]

Source Root Mappings:
[image]

[image]

Let me know if anyone knows how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an issue, there is nothing that is wrong or needs to be "fixed".

The build definition may have been deleted and recreated (or cloned, then the original deleted), causing it to start using a new folder. Each build definition gets a unique folder per build agent.

You should not rely on the build running out of any particular location. If you are currently doing so, you are making an incorrect assumption and need to start using the [built-in variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#predefined-variables) (such as `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`) that allow you to transparently reference the build's working folder.

Comment: But, as of today, 6 repositories have been updated to a new folder number. And I haven't updated the build definition for it.

Comment: Somehow every project is getting assigned a new number, without any change to the build definition. What could be the cause behind this?

Answer (score 1):

There is **SourceRootMapping** folder in the working folder and there are **Mappings.json** and **SourceFolder.json** files (`SourceRootMapping{guid} folder{build definition id} folder\sourceFolder.json`) in this folder.

So, check **lastBuildFolderNumber** in **Mappings.json** file and **SourceFolder.json** for existing mapping.

You can clear _work folder.

Related thread: [Increment in _work directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50332848/increment-in-work-directory)

Comment: But, my question is why did it change suddenly? I haven't changed my build definition for any of the repos, also didn't delete or reclone any of the build definition.

Comment: Also can I move back to the old mapping?

Comment: @Sameer It doesn't change suddenly, base on the screenshot, there are 190,197 folders, so the number is increased correctly. You can check the lastBuildFolderNumber value in Mappings.json. The reason of using 13 as folder name is that, there is the mapping to this folder, you can check sourceFolder.json. To deal with this issue, you can clear _work folder.

Comment: Oh sorry, I think you incorrectly interpreted me. I have 197 projects in VSTS; I have them since October 2017. Yesterday, suddenly for the older projects new directories were created. Like for directory 13, directory 201 was created, for 24 198 was created. They contain same repositories. Plus, I couldn't access VSTS URL after clearing _work folder. Thank god I had the backup of the folder, so I could paste the contents after finding out that clearing _work didn't work.

Comment: @Sameer It is based on the build definition instead of repositories. The folder can be deleted, but the mapping is remained. What's the content of sourceFolder.json? Are there records related to 13,201?

Comment: Well the Mappings.json say `{
  "lastBuildFolderCreatedOn": "05/22/2018 16:43:10 -07:00",
  "lastBuildFolderNumber": 205
}`

Comment: I updated the question with Source Root mappings folders.

Comment: I randomly built a project which no one touched for almost 4 months with build definition as it is, still a new directory number 207 was created for the repository. Why?

Comment: It checks the mapping in sourceFolder.json, then create the new folder based on lastBuildFolderNumber+1, but it should create 206. I recommend that you can clear _work folder, then try again to check whether the issue persist. (the name of folder will be 1, 2, 3)

Comment: If I clear the _work folder, will the mapping go back to the old one or it will start from 1?

Comment: Start from 1. You may try to modify Mappings.json and SourceFolder.json files.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I was frustrated with the same and did some digging for root cause.

ANY change to the repo URL seems to create a new Work folder. If the *Repository* name, *Project* name, or *Organization/Collection* name changes it will change the repo URL, which then spawns a new **SourceFolder.json** for that Build Definition/Pipeline under the **SourceRootMapping** folder. The latest **SourceFolder.json** is used.

You can check the **SourceRootMapping** folder and try to find the **definitionId** folder of the work folder that was replaced with a newer one. If you have multiple folders under that **definitionId** directory then check the **SourceFolder.json** files within those and see what's different, what changed to cause a new folder to be created and used.

Ex: My `D:\ADO-Terraform\_work\SourceRootMapping\542dccee-a265-44db-bae0-9b3f48d21793\1837` directory, `1837` being the **definitionID** (not the same as the work folder number), had 4 **hashKey**-named folders beneath it. I had 1 that was my original, then 1 for when I changed the repo used, then 1 for when I renamed the repo being used, then 1 for when I renamed the project this work was in.

Unfortunately I don't think there's a way to "fix" it to use the old folder. But as someone else said, you can clear out the work folder of all build definition-labeled folders (1-201, in your example) and then reset/clear the **mappings.json** file, which should make your agent start over at 1.

Before I get the "it shouldn't matter" or "use system variables" responses: I need the agent to use the same directory for every build because I'm using Terraform for deploying some simple files to our load balancer; Terraform uses state files. If the state file doesn't exist (like when the Agent uses a different work folder) Terraform tries to create the file as new on our load-balancer, which causes a "file already exists" error.