# TFS Build is downloading all branches source code of a project, which is increasing the space consumed on TFS Server

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We are using TFS to build & move source code to Web Server. Before build, files are locally copied into TFS Server. In TFS code is organized as shown in image.

Now, builds are configured on the Website Level (QA-Web1). But after the build, all the files are downloaded (for every branch and every website). This is increasing the size continuously on server, and either manual clearing is required, or space needs to be added on the server.

**Is there any way to limit the source code download to only the required folder?**

**Also, how can this action be taken for deleting existing folders? Files are created in a folder with name as numeric which has no relation with the build name. Is there any mapping between the number and the build name?**

[image: TFS Code Arrangement]

[image: Example of Folder Created on TFS Server]

[image: Sample Build Definition]

Comment: Can you share your "Get sources" step (in the build)?

Comment: Which version control are you using, Git or TFVC?

Comment: We are using TFVC

Comment: I have added sample build definition in the image above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your screenshot, `TFSAgent_Builddata_DEVQA` should be your build agent folder on workspace.

The variable  `Agent.BuildDirectory`

**The local path on the agent where all folders for a given build pipeline are created.**

There is not any mapping between the number and the build name. `..\TFSAgent_Builddata_DEVQA\525`  For each build definition, it will create a folder (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4...525). We can't influence the number.

For the concept of this part, you could also take a look at this similar question: [Increment in _work directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50332848/increment-in-work-directory)

For sub folders:

- `..\TFSAgent_Builddata_DEVQA\525\a` equal to
  `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory` The local path on the agent where
  any artifacts are copied to before being pushed to their destination.
- `..\TFSAgent_Builddata_DEVQA\525\b` equal to
  `Build.BinariesDirectory` The local path on the agent you can use as
  an output folder for compiled binaries.
- `..\TFSAgent_Builddata_DEVQA\525\s` equal to `Build.SourcesDirectory`
  The local path on the agent **where your source code files are
  downloaded**.

*[Source Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables)*

To reduce the disk space of your build agent, you could go to `Get sources` -- `Workspace mappings` as the screenshot shows, and make sure you have mapped the project you want to build.

[image]

Include with a type value of Map only the folders that your build pipeline requires. If a subfolder of a mapped folder contains files that the build pipeline does not require, map it with a type value of Cloak. For more details please refer our official tutorial here: [Mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/tfvc?view=azure-devops#mappings-workspace)

---

For other ways:

1. You can [specify build retention policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/retention?view=azure-devops), which will
   automatically **delete old completed builds to minimize clutter**.
   You modify these policies on the Retention tab of your build
   definition.
2. Use "Delete Files" utility task. The `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)` and `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`variables are useful for this. It will delete files after built successfully. For more info please refer: [Clear the work folder after each build](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/708)

Comment: Thanks. It worked. It was of great help.
I changed the Map (in Repository) section to fetch specific Folder, instead of the parent Project Folder. Attaching the screenshot in the question for other's reference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your build's workspace appropriately. You have your workspace mapped too broadly, probably to the root (`$/TFS Project`). You need to scope it more narrowly. This can be done on the Repository tab.

Comment: My issue is not of space increasing in local system where Visual Studio is installed and work space is created. My problem is, during TFS Build, the queue copies the file onto TFS Server. Here complete Project's (all branch & website) data is downloaded, instead of only the website for which TFS build is created.

Let me know if my understanding is incorrect for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Solution suggested by PatrickLu-MSFT.
"Changed the Map (in Repository) section to fetch specific Folder, instead of the parent Project Folder"
Now only required folder is getting downloaded in the Agent folder on server.[image]